# Cannot convert value of type '[Page]' to expected element type 'Page'

Tags: swift

So here is what I'm doing.  Made a table with different "rides"  the "ride cells" all link to one pageControllerView, but I want them to link to static information (var) about that one specific ride.  Meaning that each click on a tableview RideCell will link to that specific 'rides' information stored in a pageview, not to a generic page view...

The error is on Ride2 and says "cannot convert" and I am sure that it is related to the info[Page] component to the end of the line of code:

```
    func setupRides() {

    let ride2 = Ride(title: "Contacts", route: "", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "main"), info: [tron])
//  let ride3 = Ride(title: "Pirates of the Caribbean", route: "Event", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "pirates"), info: [Page(title: "Pirates of the Caribbean", message: "Soaring Over the Horizon (FP)", imageName: "main")])
```

I am just trying to get it to work on one before I bring the process to the rest.

Other important code as follows:

```
var tron: [Page] = {
let firstPage = Page(title: "Share a great listen", message: "It's free to send your books to the people in your life. Every recipient's first book is on us.", imageName: "main")
let secondPage = Page(title: "Send from your library", message: "Tap the More menu next to any book. Choose \"Send this Book\"", imageName: "main")
let thirdPage = Page(title: "Send from the player", message: "Tap the More menu in the upper corner. Choose \"Send this Book\"", imageName: "main")
return [firstPage, secondPage, thirdPage]
}()
```

This is what my Ride and Page Classes look like.

```
class Ride {
let title: String
let route: String
let image: UIImage
let info: [Page]

init(title: String, route: String, image: UIImage, info: [Page]){
    self.title = title
    self.route = route
    self.image = image
    self.info = info   
}
}

class Page {
let title: String
let message: String
let imageName: String

init(title: String, message: String, imageName: String) {
    self.title = title
    self.message = message
    self.imageName = imageName  
}
}
```

Sorry if this is a Noob question.  I did RTFF, but haven't found yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tron` is an array of `Page` since it is declared as `[Page]`.

When you do `[tron]` you are putting `tron` in another array. You now you have `[[Page]]` which is an array of arrays of `Page`.

So simply do:

```
let ride2 = Ride(title: "Contacts", route: "", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "main"), info: tron)
```